MySQL container always restarting
MySQL container always restarting. I use docker desktop in Windows 10
Logs
2024-05-14 02:31:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2024-05-14 02:31:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-05-14 02:31:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2024-05-14 02:31:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2024-05-14T02:31:02.917093Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-05-14T02:31:02.917272Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 80
2024-05-14T02:31:02.919694Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2024-05-14T02:31:02.919703Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2024-05-14T02:31:02.919794Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-14T02:31:02.919991Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

docker-compose.yml
 db:
    container_name: db-klv
    image: mysql:8.0.30
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - .db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./docker/mysql-config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    - .db-data-priv:/var/lib/mysql-priv
    - ./docker/mysql-init-scripts/init-user-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Std@12345678
      MYSQL_USER: UKlv
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: UKlv@2024
    networks:
      - klv-net

I have tried remove container, remove image, but not work

The problem seems to be caused by a conflict with the data directory. According to your provided logs, MySQL is trying to initialize a new database in a directory that already contains files, which is not allowed:
[ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
[ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

Delete the .db-data' directory in your host, to ensure that the volume mounted to /var/lib/mysql` is completely empty. Make sure that Docker is not using the volume when you try to delete the files.

I have deleted the .db-data directory, but it appears again

The error message indicates that the problem lies with the files in .db-data on the host. I could replicate this error by simply creating a file in the data directory.
sudo mkdir .db-data
sudo touch .db-data/foo.txt

db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.270279Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.270325Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 80
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.270988Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.270991Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.271012Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.271068Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.898606Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.898654Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 79
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.899330Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.899333Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.899353Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:49.899433Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db-klv exited with code 1
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
db-klv | 2024-05-14 05:56:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.524971Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.525020Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 79
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.525809Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.525812Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.525832Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db-klv | 2024-05-14T05:56:50.525892Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db-klv exited with code 1

Delete or move that directory.  But before you do that, make sure that the MySQL container has been stopped by running docker-compose down.
# If there's nothing of value in the directory.
sudo rm -rf .db-data
# If you want to keep the content of the directory.
sudo mv .db-data /tmp/

You might want to also remove the other data directory.
# If there's nothing of value in the directory.
sudo rm -rf .db-data-priv
# If you want to keep the content of the directory.
sudo mv .db-data-priv /tmp/


How to run without --initialize?

You're right. I think that this is being called via the entrypoint script in the base image.

How to run without --initialize? I run the container using the command “docker compose up -d”

I have added two options for getting rid of that directory. When you remove/move it the problem should be resolved.
